# Division with float did not give expected result in C#

Tags: c#, double, division

I am facing a problem in dividing numbers in c#.

See my code in C# for division

```
double openRate = 0,

long a=542;
long b=4795;

openRate =(a/b)*100
```

This gives `11.303..` in my calculator .
But c# gives me  `0.0`

What could be reason?

Comment: integer division....asked a bazillion times in many forms

Comment: You say "division with float" in your question - but both your operands are `long` values. So you're doing division with longs... and then just assigning the result to a `double`. That's not the same thing.

Comment: either the above, you have yet to step over this line in debugger, or your leaving a method without taking the value with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
long a = 542;
long b = 4795;
```

Since because `a / b` is calculated as an *integral value*; any fractional part was dropped. So `a / b` is equal `0` at this point not `0,113..`.

From elemantary school math;

```
0 * 100 = 0
```

Your calculator use probably floating division so actually it calculates this like;

```
double openRate = 0;

long a = 542;
long b = 4795;

openRate =((double)a / b) * 100; // 11.303...
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are integers and get divided using the `operator/` of `long`, resulting in an integral division.

> 542 / 4795 = 0<s>.113</s>

After this they got multiplied with 100, which is an integer, either.

> 0 * 100 = 0

Last but not least the (still integral) result get's converted into an `double`. What you want to write is something like this:

```
openRate = ((double)a / (double)b) * 100.0;
```